# Why do we tell functions from relations in structures?

Tags: logic, model-theory

A relation is a set of ordered pairs (a,b)

A function is a relation (a,b) which satisfies the following conditions:

For all a, there is one and only one b

Therefore, all functions are relations.

In structures, we distinguish three kinds of symbols: functions, relations and constants

If all functions are relations, why don't we divide the symbols only into relations and constants?

Comment: A relation is a set of ordered pairs. Not an ordered pair.

Comment: Oh, thanks, Asaf! I'll fix it!

Answer (score 2):

It is true that every function symbol can be traded for a relation symbol along with some axioms stating that the symbol defines a function etc etc. You can also replace a constant symbol by a relation symbol and the axioms that there exists a unique element satisfying that relation.

But function and constant symbols make it easier to create new terms. And this allows for simplification in some aspects.

Consider the language of groups, with a binary operation $*$ and a constant $1$. If you replace them relations, then the axioms for a group will look like this:

1. $\exists y(1(y)\forall x(1(x)\rightarrow x=y))$ here we are saying that $1$ is a constant symbol.
2. $\forall x\forall y\exists z(*(x,y,z)\land\forall w(*(x,y,w)\rightarrow w=z))$ here we are saying that $*$ is a binary function symbol.
3. $\forall x\forall y\forall z(\exists w\exists u\exists v(*(x,y,w)\land *(w,z,u)\land *(y,z,v)\land *(x,v,u)))$ here we say that $*$ is associative.
4. $\forall x\exists y\exists z(*(x,y,z)\land 1(z))$ here we say that there exists an inverse for every element.
5. $\forall x\exists y(1(y)\land *(x,y,x)\land *(y,x,x))$ and here we say that $1$ is neutral for $*$.

Are these axioms really easier to handle compared to $\forall x\forall y\forall z((x*y)*z=x*(y*z))$? What about when you want to write an axiom stating that "Every element has order of at most $n$", then it will be some horribly long statement $\forall x\exists y_1\ldots\exists y_n(1(y_n)\land *(x,x,y_1)\land *(y_1,x,y_2)\land\ldots\land *(y_{n-1},x,y_n))$. How is this easier than $x*x*\ldots *x=1$, $n$ times?

So terms are useful, and we use functions and constant symbols for terms. This fact can be seem very clearly in set theory. The language only include the binary relations $\in,=$. But we add constants like $\varnothing$ and $\omega$ and so on; and we add functions like $\mathcal P(\bullet)$ for the power sets and $\bigcup\bullet$ for the union, and so on. We do it because it makes our lives so much easier.

But it is true, at the end of the day we can always go back to a relational language. Only that the cost is that we make every statement and proof vastly more complex, and introduce quantifiers everywhere. And this means that we also lose the ability to talk about "quantifier elimination" which is a useful property.

Comment: I'd expand a bit on quantifier elimination, because it's a very good point, but my answer is long enough. If someone else wants to do it, I'll be happy to see what they have to say!

Comment: That's a very nice answer, but I am not sure I understand your point about quantifier elimination. A QE theorem typically says that every formula in such-and-such a theory is equivalent to a quantifier-free formula. If you replace all the function symbols by relation symbols, then the axioms saying that all those relation symbols actually denote functions become part of the theory and the quantifiers that you have to introduce all over the place when you "unnest" terms are still eliminable (but you may have made the algorithm for eliminating them incredibly difficult to describe). ...

Comment: @Rob: In the language of rings, if you make everything into a relation; how can you write $x^2+2=0$ as a quantifier free formula? I count at least three quantifiers that are needed there, maybe four. Or something like $x+y=z$?

Comment: (I realised my error almost as soon as I hit return): what I just wrote only applies to sentences. If there are free variables, it won't be possible to eliminate quantifiers in general: there will very likely be no way you can get an equivalent of y = f(f(x)) without quantifiers. So unnesting terms is a bad idea if quantifier elimination for formulas with free variables is important to you (and it is important in many cases). @Asaf Karagila: I think that between us we have said what needs to be said about quantifier elimination in this context.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to say in that last sentence/first comment.